# The pronunciation of "protester"

Tags: pronunciation

In this press conference held every day by Hong Kong Police, the police officer pronounced "protester" as "PRO-tes-ter". I checked the dictionaries such as the Cambridge Online and Longman Online and could only find it pronounced as /prəˈtestə r/. Did the native English officer with the British accent pronounce the word wrongly?

[image]
(Watch the part of the video that features the native speaker, who spoke from 29:09 to 32:37) [www.youtube.com](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FzGUqYdKalo)

Comment: The version with the initial stress is generally AmE, but since it’s such a ‘news word’ likely to appear in news programmes on tv, I suspect it’s spreading. To me there’s a difference between a /prəˈtestər/ (someone who objects or protests to something) and a /ˈproʊtestər/ (someone who takes part in a protest march of some kind), but I have absolutely no idea if that’s just me, or if such a distinction is actually common.

Answer (score 5):

The pronunciation *proTESTer* /prəˈtestər/ corresponds to the stress pattern of the verb *proTEST*. That verb has a pronunciation with stress on the second syllable in both British English and American English.

The noun *PROtest* usually has first-syllable stress in both British English and American English.

For some speakers (not all), there exists, alongside the verb *proTEST,* a verb "PROtest" that is stressed on the first syllable and more or less means "participate in a PROtest". The stress pattern of this verb is derived from that of the noun. The verb *PROtest* seems to be more common in American English than in British English, but it is used by some British English speakers.

The pronunciation "PROtester", with stress on the first syllable, is most likely based on the verb "PROtest". This topic is covered in the 2011 Language Log post "[Protesters](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2982)", by Eric Baković.

The comments on that page have some useful additional information, such as this:

> in his pronunciation dictionary, John Wells gives both options for the verb in both BrE and AmE.
>
> But more interestingly, under *protester,* he gives the results of one of his pronunciation polls, albeit for BrE only:
>
> *Preference poll, British English: [stress on the second syllable] 69%; [stress on the first syllable] 31% (born since 1982: 45%)*
>
> Note that the polls were done on paper, via regular mail (!), and – if I remember correctly – essentially on a self-report volunteer basis. So any "new" trends may be underreported. Or overreported ;)

–Jarek Weckwerth, February 21, 2011 @ 6:34 pm

Comment: no, the verb can never have the first-syllable stress.

Comment: I meant in British English. American English may be the opposite.

Comment: @LouisLiu Where did you get that from? That's definitely wrong.

Comment: @Zebrafish in BrE it's the **noun** protest which has stress on the first syllable, the verb on the second.

Comment: @WeatherVane I agree that the noun has the stress on the first syllable, but to say that the verb can never have the stress on the first syllable as a verb in BrE is wrong. That's whether BrE is used in the looser sense of English from Canada, Australia, New Zealand, or in the stricter sense of English just from Great Britain. I'm saying that based on my experience and a check I did on Youglish. In case people don't believe, here is a link to a news story from a UK news outlet, just one example of many. https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=9&v=0GgsfrhZdpw

Comment: Another, https://youtu.be/ZmSF9gVz9pg?t=820 , and another https://youtu.be/bIe3nvBo8g0?t=235 . another: https://youtu.be/3pbTmXsfiYk?t=290 . it shouldn't take me to get records for people to believe that BrE speakers do in fact say this with a first-syllable stress.

Comment: The link's second paragraph says the same as I did, about the pronunciation of the verb and noun forms of **protest**. From there, is his opinion. *In other words, I wouldn't describe the act of someone who protésts to my analysis here as a prótest, and I would also be very surprised to walk by a prótest and to hear them chanting "We protést!"* and it's an opinion which I don't share.

Comment: @Zebrafish in your link to a UK news outlet, the speaker puts equal stress on both syllables, as if uncertain of how she should say "to protest".

Comment: @WeatherVane I disagree with that, but criticism accepted. There are many other instances of it you can see, some I've linked. I've only gone through about 30 results from about 500. I also speak from experience, whatever that's worth. What I do agree with is that "protest" with second-syllable stress is never heard when it's a noun, but not the original claim.

Comment: @Zebrafish I agree that it is getting increasingly hard to assert that in one dialect is *such-and-such* and another is *this-and-that*. There are tendencies but with cross-fertilisation some British people like to sound like Americans and vice versa.